# No Internet Access After Updating From 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS

Tags: networking, server, internet, dns

I recently updated to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS from the update prompt within 18.04 LTS. Everything seems fine afterward except that I've lost outside internet access. My interfaces are enabled and I'm able to ping them on the network, connect to Samba, MySQL, etc. but no outside access.

My two interfaces are the onboard gigabit NIC, which is my primary, and is connected to my router and a 10GbE NIC that is connected directly to my main PC, strictly for Samba. I've also attached a wireless adapter which encounters the same issue. I've tried disabling all other interfaces aside from the primary, I set my DNS to 8.8.8.8 in /etc/systemd/resolved (I'm able to ping 1.1.1.1 and 8.8.8.8) without any luck. I ran route -n and shows my gateway for 0.0.0.0 as 10.0.0.1 (my router), so I don't believe its a default gateway issue.

**EDIT**

Contents of /etc/resolv.conf:

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 127.0.1.1
```

Contents of /etc/systemd/resolved.conf:

```
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#  under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.
#
# Entries in this file show the compile time defaults.
# You can change settings by editing this file.
# Defaults can be restored by simply deleting this file.
#
# See resolved.conf(5) for details

[Resolve]
DNS=8.8.8.8
#FallbackDNS=
#Domains=
#LLMNR=no
#MulticastDNS=no
#DNSSEC=no
#DNSOverTLS=no
#Cache=yes
#DNSStubListener=yes
#ReadEtcHosts=yes
```

Note that "DNS=8.8.8.8" was originally "#DNS=" until I changed it as a test. No luck

Both resolvctl status and systemd-resolve --status return:

```
Failed to get global data: Unit dbus-org.freedesktop.resolve1.service not found.
```

Comment: If you can ping `8.8.8.8` then your issue likely is not internet connection, but domain name resolution. Have you looked at  `sudo resolvectl status` or `systemd-resolve --status` for current DNS IP? You should also examine `/etc/resolv.conf` for the appropriate `nameserver 8.8.8.8` line (if you are using that for `systemd-resolved`). Better yet, show us what you have in `/etc/resolv.conf` and `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf`

Comment: Also, check whether your `/etc/resolv.conf` doesn't link to `/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf`.  The correct link should be to `resolv.conf`. The following command will take care of removing the bad link, creating a new one, and restarting corresponding services `sudo rm -f /etc/resolv.conf && sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf && sudo service systemd-resolved restart && sudo systemctl restart networking`. Your DNS resolution should work afterwards

Comment: Interesting. After running that command I get
"Failed to restart systemd-resolved.service: Unit systemd-resolved.service is masked."

Comment: Unmasked the service, started it, and now it's working. Thanks for your help!